# Scroll view with container view doesn't adjust the content size correctly

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a view hierarchy arranged this way:

```
main view
---- scroll view
-------- label
-------- label
-------- text view
-------- horizontal stack view
-------- divider view (UIView)
-------- label
-------- container view (embeds a child view controller)
```

**The embedded child view controller is a *UICollectionViewController*.**

Now the problem is that the collection view controller contains a lot of elements, and I expected the scroll view to automatically adjust its content size in order to take into account of the collection view height too, but it doesn't. So at the moment I can just see the first elements of the collection view, but I cannot scroll down. I tried to manually adjust the content size of the collection view this way:

```
func adjustContentSize() {
    var contentRect: CGRect = .zero

    for subview in self.scrollView.subviews {
        contentRect = contentRect.union(subview.frame)
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size
}
```

But the content size is still incorrect: it is exactly equal to the window size, even if it should be a lot higher in order to make place for all the elements inside the collection view. I think that the problem has to do mainly with the fact that I am embedding a child view controller, because normally the scroll view content size is adjusted automatically. But what to do in this case? how to tell the right content size to the scroll view?

Comment: Don't use `self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size` ... use constraints and let auto-layout do it for you.

Comment: @DonMag Normally a constraint is a relationship between two views. In this case I really wouldn't know how to express a similar constraint, I could only set it to the height of a single view, not of many views. Any suggestion?

Comment: *"The embedded child view controller is a UICollectionViewController."* -- how are you defining the height of the collection view? Are you just having it fit to the size of the container view? Or are you trying to get the container view to change its height based on the height of the collection view?

Comment: @DonMag The collection view doesn't have any constraint since it's the collection view controller's main view. The container view instead is pinned inside the scroll view.

Comment: You say you're using a *"container view"* -- do you mean you're laying this out in IB / Storyboard, and you're using a `UIContainerView` with an embedded collection view controller? Or are you doing this via code, and you're just using the term *container view* to mean you're creating a `UIView` and adding the collection view as a subview of that view?

Comment: The first one. Yes, I am doing it in the storyboard.

Comment: If you are laying this out in Storyboard, simply set up your constraints as normal. It doesn't matter that you are using a `UIContainerView` ... just make sure you have a top-to-bottom chain of vertical constraints (and heights), and left-to-right chain of horizontal constraints (and widths where needed).

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the implications of the fact that the collection view controller is embedded, and inside a container view: you cannot constraint a view from one view controller to another. This is why the collection view doesn't have any constraint: because it's the main view of the view controller.

Comment: You don't constrain the ***collection view*** -- you constrain the ***container view***. The collection view simply uses the space provided by the container (its auto-sized when embedded).

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri can you post a demo project here using Github or any other so that we can give it a try?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing different when setting constraints on a Container View than on any other view.

Here is your layout, with constraints:

[image]

at run-time, it looks like this:

[image]

and, scrolled:

[image]

Here is all the code needed (the collection view uses Horizontal Flow):

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Ramy
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 8/7/19.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

}

extension UIColor {
    static var random: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: .random(in: 0...1),
                       green: .random(in: 0...1),
                       blue: .random(in: 0...1),
                       alpha: 1.0)
    }
}

class EmbeddedCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ReuseID")
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ReuseID", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.random
        return cell

    }

}
```

and the source to the Storyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14490.70" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14490.49"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="Ramy" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="jJS-Jp-5Wb">
                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="28" width="359" height="631"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label 1" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="XwC-bl-fns">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="153" y="8" width="53.5" height="20.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99806135890000003" green="0.96808904409999996" blue="0.12760734560000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label 2" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="VcB-Di-yle">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="151.5" y="40.5" width="56" height="20.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99806135890000003" green="0.96808904409999996" blue="0.12760734560000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                    <textView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" textAlignment="natural" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="2P9-JD-ezE">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="59.5" y="73" width="240" height="128"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="240" id="RSb-O4-Jy1"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="128" id="ZNr-Tq-dig"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                        <string key="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.</string>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                        <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="sentences"/>
                                    </textView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="fillEqually" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Urd-av-tKj">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="54" y="213" width="251.5" height="20.5"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Horizontal" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="iJ9-BV-XXm">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="78.5" height="20.5"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99806135890000003" green="0.96808904409999996" blue="0.12760734560000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Stack" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="SlW-MH-lZj">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="86.5" y="0.0" width="78.5" height="20.5"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99806135890000003" green="0.96808904409999996" blue="0.12760734560000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="View" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="usj-S2-wXe">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="173" y="0.0" width="78.5" height="20.5"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99806135890000003" green="0.96808904409999996" blue="0.12760734560000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Ube-Ox-WG0" userLabel="Divider View">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="29.5" y="253.5" width="300" height="4"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.14913141730000001" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="300" id="3r0-U8-e4h"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="4" id="8Zh-29-VuE"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </view>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label 3" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="t4g-6L-Fxz">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="151.5" y="277.5" width="56.5" height="20.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99806135890000003" green="0.96808904409999996" blue="0.12760734560000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                    <containerView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Ae9-nr-NPW">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="12" y="310" width="335" height="500"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.16078431369999999" green="0.62352941179999999" blue="0.81960784310000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="500" id="Ugi-NN-btd"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                        <connections>
                                            <segue destination="iKt-In-mH7" kind="embed" id="xc0-HZ-ykL"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </containerView>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99942404029999998" green="0.88699374509999995" blue="0.6455106089" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Ae9-nr-NPW" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="jJS-Jp-5Wb" secondAttribute="leading" constant="12" id="46G-Do-tx2"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Ae9-nr-NPW" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="jJS-Jp-5Wb" secondAttribute="width" constant="-24" id="9Gx-Qt-KD7"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="VcB-Di-yle" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="2P9-JD-ezE" secondAttribute="centerX" id="AbA-b2-Dc2"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Ube-Ox-WG0" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="t4g-6L-Fxz" secondAttribute="centerX" id="J1X-MF-qh8"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Ae9-nr-NPW" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="J4e-Iv-CbW"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="VcB-Di-yle" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="XwC-bl-fns" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="12" id="Lbs-Pa-kn0"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Urd-av-tKj" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="2P9-JD-ezE" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="12" id="MnP-kq-VMd"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Ube-Ox-WG0" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Urd-av-tKj" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="Nzj-mz-NBe"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="2P9-JD-ezE" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="VcB-Di-yle" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="12" id="PV8-rx-82P"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="t4g-6L-Fxz" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="Ae9-nr-NPW" secondAttribute="centerX" id="R8B-Yu-eaX"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Ae9-nr-NPW" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="12" id="Vl6-pC-fR7"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="t4g-6L-Fxz" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Ube-Ox-WG0" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="dzM-uC-vDg"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="2P9-JD-ezE" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="Urd-av-tKj" secondAttribute="centerX" id="gIG-Ln-0ci"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="XwC-bl-fns" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="jJS-Jp-5Wb" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="h2g-bu-iYg"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Ae9-nr-NPW" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="t4g-6L-Fxz" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="12" id="k5A-Ht-wuD"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="XwC-bl-fns" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="VcB-Di-yle" secondAttribute="centerX" id="s7H-0G-55o"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Urd-av-tKj" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="Ube-Ox-WG0" secondAttribute="centerX" id="wIn-jA-Hwn"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="jJS-Jp-5Wb" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="HZI-i3-eQL"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="jJS-Jp-5Wb" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="TrF-oh-lbk"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="jJS-Jp-5Wb" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="gCW-Kv-Vma"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="jJS-Jp-5Wb" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="mdg-vi-3RB"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="138.40000000000001" y="138.98050974512745"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Embedded Collection View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="8Wg-59-nK4">
            <objects>
                <collectionViewController id="iKt-In-mH7" customClass="EmbeddedCollectionViewController" customModule="Ramy" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <collectionView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" dataMode="prototypes" id="pbM-fa-YQc">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="335" height="500"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <collectionViewFlowLayout key="collectionViewLayout" scrollDirection="horizontal" minimumLineSpacing="10" minimumInteritemSpacing="10" id="Sd4-5y-JzD">
                            <size key="itemSize" width="50" height="50"/>
                            <size key="headerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                            <size key="footerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                            <inset key="sectionInset" minX="0.0" minY="0.0" maxX="0.0" maxY="0.0"/>
                        </collectionViewFlowLayout>
                        <cells>
                            <collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" misplaced="YES" id="UTC-Yv-lrd">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <view key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                </view>
                            </collectionViewCell>
                        </cells>
                        <connections>
                            <outlet property="dataSource" destination="iKt-In-mH7" id="KsO-Bh-EEm"/>
                            <outlet property="delegate" destination="iKt-In-mH7" id="IOW-gi-oV8"/>
                        </connections>
                    </collectionView>
                </collectionViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="PLD-Y7-bEq" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="888.79999999999995" y="312.14392803598201"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: Can you please upload the storyboard file?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri - I already posted the source for the storyboard file. Just select your storyboard, right-click and select `Open As -> Source Code`, delete everything there and copy/paste the Storyboard source from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you can not set the constraints for all these views? I know one constraint is a relationship between two views, but multiple constraints can make relationships for all these views.

for your case, you have 7 views inside scrollview, you can do something like this,

```
scrollview.top = view1.top
view2.top = view1.bottom
view3.top = view2.bottom
...
view7.bottom = scrollview.bottom
// don't forget to set this
scrollview.top = scrollviewParent.top
scrollview.bottom = scrollviewParent.bottom
scrollview.leading = scrollviewParent.leading
scrollview.trailing = scrollviewParent.trailing
```

so all these constraints should do the work.

Comment: I am already setting constraints this way, the problem is that the scroll view doesn't have the correct content size.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is a confusion of how scroll views work. A scroll view is a "fixed" height region on the screen that is scrollable across its "contentView" height (talking about a vertical scroll here).

Of course your main scroll view will wrap around the content and adjust height automatically, but remember UICollectionView is also an extension of UIScrollView and it will scroll across the height of it's contentView within the bounds set by its parent view (here the container view)

I hope you see the problem now, you set a fixed size or use auto layout to determine the height of the "ContainerView" and then the main scroll view adjusts its "contentView" based on this. This also forces your UICollectionView to be scrollable across only that height. The problem is if your collectionview is dynamic, you don't know the height to set it to at build time. What happens is you can scroll to the end of the main scrollview and it will show the inferred or fixed height of the containerview which **should be scrollable too within that height!**! (a nested scrollview if you will)

The solution seems to be as follows. You will need to infer the number of rows of your collectionview and set the height of the containerview to match this (height_per_item * no_of_rows). Then the scroll view 
 will wrap around this total height and provide scrolling across the full contentView height (seems prudent to turn off vertical scrolling in collectionview since it wont be used. I'm not fully aware of performance implications of having nested scroll views)

Comment: Still not clear to me: I am trying to set the height of the container view to a higher value (e.g. 800), but the scrollable content doesn't get adjusted and the content size of the scroll view is still the same.

Comment: remember to attach the bottom layout constraint of the "container view" to the bottom of the "content view"

Comment: As an additional point. Ensure that a UIScrollView has only 1 child view which wraps all others views around (this is a common practice). Then this view effectively becomes your contentView of the ScrollView and its height will be taken for scroll contentview height

Answer (score 0):

IF the Problem is ScrollView ContentSize.you should set content Size based on (Height + margin of component(Label,TextView,StatckView)) plus CollectionView.contentSize.height

and Constraint Should be set after Reloading of CollectionView on Controller B

Example

**ViewControllerA**

```
let ViewControllerB = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerB") as! ViewControllerB
        ViewControllerB.compltion = { collectionHeight in
            ScrollView.heightConstaint.constant = 500 + collectionHeight
        }
```

here 500 is top+bottom margin + height of other component(stackView,Label,TextView)

**ViewControllerB**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectioView.reloadData()
        self.collectioView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: {
            (result) in
            if self.compltion != nil {
                self.compltion!(self.collectioView.contentSize.height)
            }
        })


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```